# Java TimePicker does not return right value

Tags: java, android, timepicker

In android project I have this class

```
package mycalories.com.jalle.mycalories;

import android.app.Dialog;
import android.app.DialogFragment;
import android.app.TimePickerDialog;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.text.format.DateFormat;
import android.text.format.Time;
import android.widget.TimePicker;

import java.util.Calendar;

public class TimePickerFragment extends DialogFragment implements
        TimePickerDialog.OnTimeSetListener {

    public static interface OnTimeSetListener {
        void onTimeSet(Time time);
    }

    private OnTimeSetListener onTimeSetListener;

    @Override
    public Dialog onCreateDialog(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        final Calendar c = Calendar.getInstance();
        int hour = c.get(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY);
        int minute = c.get(Calendar.MINUTE);

       return new TimePickerDialog(getActivity(), this, hour, minute,
                DateFormat.is24HourFormat(getActivity()));
    }

    public void onTimeSet(TimePicker view, int hourOfDay, int minute) {
       if (onTimeSetListener != null) {
           Time newTime =new Time(hourOfDay+":"+minute+ "");
            onTimeSetListener.onTimeSet(newTime);
        }
    }

    public void setOnTimeSetListener(OnTimeSetListener onTimeSetListener) {
        this.onTimeSetListener = onTimeSetListener;
    }
}
```

that should return Time selected. And in the main activity I have button and a text field:

```
Button btnTime = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btnTime);
        btnTime.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            public void onClick(View v) {
                TimePickerFragment timePicker = new TimePickerFragment();
                timePicker.show(getFragmentManager(), "timePicker");
                timePicker.setOnTimeSetListener(new OnTimeSetListener() {

                  @Override
                    public void onTimeSet(Time time) {

                    //  SimpleDateFormat HHMM = new SimpleDateFormat("hh:mm");

                        final EditText txtTime = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.txtTime);
                        txtTime.setText(time.toString());
                    }
                });
            }
        });
```

After selecting time I should have in format hh:mm but instead I got 19700101T00000011:55(4,0,0,0,0)
(obviously current time is not selected but default one)
I guess that the method `onTimeSet`is not right. Any idea ?

And one more q : How do I use same TimePicker class for multiple textboxes in diff activities ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[`Time`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/text/format/Time.html) API has 3 constructors: no argument, `String` argument, and other `Time` argument. The constructor you are using, which is the `String` one, only accepts timezone as the expected value, and it will set the date to Jan 1, 1970.

> public Time (String timezone)
>
> Construct a Time object in the timezone named by
>   the string argument "timezone". The time is initialized to Jan 1,
>   1970.

If you want to return the `Time` with today's date and selected time, try changing the code to

```
public void onTimeSet(TimePicker view, int hourOfDay, int minute) {
    if (onTimeSetListener != null) {
        Time newTime = new Time();
        newTime.setToNow();
        newTime.hour = hourOfDay;
        newTime.minute = minute;
        onTimeSetListener.onTimeSet(newTime);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Knowing that you eventually want to display the time in `hh:mm` format, it would be easier to implement your interface method using the `java.util.Date` class, which `SimpleDateFormat` "plays nice" with. In the `TimePickerFragment` class, change the following:

```
public static interface OnTimeSetListener {
    void onTimeSet(Date date);
}

public void onTimeSet(TimePicker view, int hourOfDay, int minute) {
    if (onTimeSetListener != null) {
        Date date = new Date();
        date.setHours(hourOfDay);
        date.setMinutes(minute);
        onTimeSetListener.onTimeSet(date);
    }
}
```

And in the `onClick()` method:

```
public void onClick(View v)
{
    TimePickerFragment timePicker = new TimePickerFragment();
    timePicker.show(getFragmentManager(), "timePicker");
    timePicker.setOnTimeSetListener(new TimePickerFragment.OnTimeSetListener() {
            @Override
            public void onTimeSet(Date date)
            {
                final EditText txtTime = (EditText) findViewById(R.id. txtTime);
                SimpleDateFormat HHMM = new SimpleDateFormat("hh:mm");
                txtTime.setText(HHMM.format(date));
            }
        }
    );
}
```